# How do i send a swap Jupiter's into Python?

Tags: python

im trying to buy a token in solana dex using jupiter dex, i do the next steps:

1- Get Quote
2- With the quote i get the swapTransaction

How do i send this "swapTransaction" variable and create the swap in the live solana network?

I have this code:

```
import asyncio
import base64
import solders
from solana.transaction import Transaction
from solathon import PublicKey, Keypair
from solana.rpc.types import TxOpts
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solders import message, transaction

def send_transaction(swap_transaction, opts):

    client = Client("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com")
    sender = Keypair().from_private_key("XXX")

    raw_tx = solders.transaction.VersionedTransaction.from_bytes(base64.b64decode(swap_transaction))
    signed_txn = sender.sign(bytes(raw_tx))
    s_signed_txn = solders.transaction.VersionedTransaction.populate(raw_tx.message, [signed_txn])
    encoded_tx = base64.b64encode(bytes(s_signed_txn)).decode('utf-8')

    result = client.send_transaction(s_signed_txn, opts)
    txid = result.value

    print("TxID: {txid}")

async def perform_swap(sent_amount, input_token_mint, output_token_mint):

    tmpSwap = "swapTransaction"

    opts = TxOpts(skip_preflight=True, max_retries=3)
    send_transaction(tmpSwap, opts)

asyncio.run(perform_swap("1000", "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112", "5HkMzQzo5wiXyNgsWJSm3F8jQYMSaUZ6z5Vd7Z1yCsC9"))
```

Comment: My code is running and giving the txnid but when opening in explorer it is not showing anything. what can be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you try to use the solders package more as it incoperates a lot of the code present in the solana-py package and is updated more frequently and is more relevant.

Try using `sender.sign_message(message.to_bytes_versioned(raw_tx.message))` instead when signing the message.
When sending the transaction to the blockchain to be executed I prefer to send the transaction to the blockchain using the httpx package. So instead of using `result = client.send_transaction(x, y)` you would post it to the blockchain as shown below.

```
import asyncio
import httpx
import base64
from solders.transaction import VersionedTransaction  # type: ignore
from solders.keypair import Keypair  # type: ignore
from solders import message
import solders


async def send_transaction(swap_transaction):
    sender = Keypair().from_private_key("XXX")

    raw_tx = solders.transaction.VersionedTransaction.from_bytes(
        base64.b64decode(swap_transaction)
    )
    signed_txn = sender.sign_message(message.to_bytes_versioned(raw_tx.message))
    s_signed_txn = solders.transaction.VersionedTransaction.populate(
        raw_tx.message, [signed_txn]
    )
    encoded_tx = base64.b64encode(bytes(s_signed_txn)).decode("utf-8")

    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    data = {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "id": 1,
        "method": "sendTransaction",
        "params": [
            encoded_tx,
            {
                "skipPreflight": True,
                "preflightCommitment": "finalized",
                "encoding": "base64",
                "maxRetries": None,
                "minContextSlot": None,
            },
        ],
    }

    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        response = await client.post(
            "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com",
            headers=headers,
            json=data,
        )

    return response.json()


async def main():
    result = await send_transaction(swap_transaction)
    txid = result["result"]
    print(f"https://explorer.solana.com/tx/{txid}")
    return result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```